# React Context is always an empty object, no matter what I do

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So, I'm aware of cyclical references, and have put my context in another file:

```
import React from 'react'

export const MainContext = React.createContext({ test: 'test!'})
```

I then wrap my 'App' file's `render` method with it, like so:

```
<MainContext.Provider value={'Literally anything, Im gonna ignore it anyway.'}>
    <div>
        { other stuff }
    </div>
</MainContext.Provider>
```

then, in my child components, I import the context and set it as the contextType:

```
import { MainContext } from 'context'

class Status extends Component {
    static contextType = MainContext

    render(){
        console.log(this.props) // nothing
        console.log(this.context) // you guessed it! nothing either

        return (<div></div>)
    }
}
```

Obviously, as nothing in life is that simple, I'm just getting an empty object no matter what I do. Is there something I'm missing? I've followed every guide I can find...

Comment: How and where are you using your Status component?

Comment: It's a child component, but a few levels down. Would it being under a <Route> make any difference? I'm trying to think of how it could differ from your example, but I'm not sure what'd remove context like that...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate this, and it worked.
link to the codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/62lvlpypr). Hope this helps.